# Variable in AnsiStringT template

Tags: delphi, switch-statement, c++builder, codepages

I currently use the conversion function which looks like this (C++ Builder):

```cpp
UnicodeString OutputInCodePage(const int CodePage, std::string& InStr, const unsigned Offs)
  {
  switch (CodePage)
      {
      default:
      case 0:     return AnsiStringT<0>   (InStr.substr(Offs).c_str());  // System default
      case 037:   return AnsiStringT<037> (InStr.substr(Offs).c_str());  // IBM037   IBM EBCDIC US-Canada
      case 437:   return AnsiStringT<437> (InStr.substr(Offs).c_str());  // IBM437   OEM United States
      case 500:   return AnsiStringT<500> (InStr.substr(Offs).c_str());  // IBM500   IBM EBCDIC International
      // And many more following...
      }
  }
```

But I really want to avoid the use of huge switch/case - something like this:

```cpp
UnicodeString OutputInCodePage(const int CodePage, std::string& InStr, const unsigned Offs)
  {
  return AnsiStringT<CodePage> (InStr.substr(Offs).c_str());
  }
```

That doesn't work and gives me `E2396 Template argument must be a constant expression` error.

Is there a way to re-do the code so I can use `std::string` raw data conversion (into UnicodeString) based on CodePage parameter without a huge switch/case list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is indeed a much easier way to handle this - use the [`RawByteString`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.RawByteString) type and the [`SetCodePage()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SetCodePage) function, eg:

```cpp
UnicodeString OutputInCodePage(const int CodePage, const std::string  &InStr, const unsigned Offs)
{
    RawByteString out(InStr.c_str() + Offs);
    SetCodePage(out, CodePage, false);
    return out;
}
```

Alternatively, use the [`UnicodeFromLocaleChars()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.UnicodeFromLocaleChars) function:

```cpp
UnicodeString OutputInCodePage(const int CodePage, const std::string &InStr, const unsigned Offs)
{
    UnicodeString out;

    const char *p_in = InStr.c_str() + Offs;
    int in_len = InStr.length() - Offs;

    int out_len = UnicodeFromLocaleChars(CodePage, 0, p_in, in_len, NULL, 0);
    if (out_len > 0)
    {
        out.SetLength(out_len);
        UnicodeFromLocaleChars(CodePage, 0, p_in, in_len, out.c_str(), out_len);
    }

    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply!

Comment: Note that `UnicodeFromLocaleChars' can be pretty slow on non-Windows platforms, because of the need to supply a locale name on these platforms. I developed a perfect hash that converts this pretty fast (the hash is just a % and an exclusive or, IIRC). I'll take a look. It is approx. 10 times as fast as the POSIX version in System.pas, and in some code, that can really make a difference.